# How do i fill my parameter req.body with axios (Vue.js) to my Express.js server

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, axios

Im trying to send a connect call to my api from my vue (i use vue.js),
but when i get the object req.body in my back, the object is empty

I've read this : [Axios post request.body is empty object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40859299/axios-post-request-body-is-empty-object)
but it didn't help me

(it works from Postman with the body filled and the option x-www-form-encoded)

i got this got from my Vue :
*My vue* service.js

```js
import Axios from 'axios';

class APIClient {
    constructor () {
        this.client = Axios.create({
            baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080'
        });
    }

    async connect () {

        const params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.append('mail', 'test');
        params.append('pwd', 'mypwd');
        return await this.client.get('/api/user/auth', params);

    }
```

and i got this in my back :
index.ts :

```js
import express from "express";
var cors = require('cors');
import "reflect-metadata";
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const http = require('http');
const MainRouter = require('./routes/main_router');

let port = 8080;
const server = express();

server.use(cors({origin: true}))
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

let mainRouter = new MainRouter(server);

const httpServer = http.createServer(server);
httpServer.listen(port);
console.log('Server is listening');
```

and the main_router.ts

```js
import express from 'express';
import mysql from "promise-mysql";

export default class MainRouter {

    public server: express.Express;
    
    constructor (server: express.Express) {
        super();
        this.server = server; 
        this.server.get("/api/user/auth", async (req: any, res: any) => {
            if (req.body) //the req.body is equal to {} instead of {mail: 'test', ...
                return res.json(await this.userManager.getUserByCredidentials(req.body));
            else return res.json([])
        });    
    }
}

module.exports = MainRouter;
```

I don't know if i have something to add in my express server or in my vue with axios ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are passing the `mail` and `pwd` as GET parameters and not at the request body. You can access the using `req.query`, but ....
2. You should avoid sending creds as parameters of the url with GET, use the body and POST instead. For more information see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43965418).

Here is an example:

```
return await this.client.post('/api/user/auth', {
   mail: "test",
   pwd: "mypwd"
});
```

and of course do not forget to change `this.server.get("/api/user/auth",...` to `this.server.post("/api/user/auth",...`

Comment: ok thank you, that worked ! i won't pass credits through my url